# How to add percent symbol to each value in a row where index finished on defined string in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have Data Frame in Python Pandas like the below:

```
IDX    | col1  | col2
-----------------
X_sum  | 548   | 1200
X_perc | 3.82  | 57.45
Y_sum  | 123   | 435
Y_perc | 11.98 | 22.87
```

And column "IDX" is here as index column. And I need to add symbol "%" next to each value in row where index finished as "_perc".

So as a result I need something like this:

```
IDX    | col1   | col2
--------------------------
X_sum  | 548    | 1200
X_perc | 3.82%  | 57.45%
Y_sum  | 123    | 435
Y_perc | 11.98% | 22.87%
```

How can I do that in Python Pandas?

Comment: Please, include what you've tried so far

Comment: Please keep in mind that adding a percentage sign will require the column be converted to a string; which might make life harder where calculations are required.

Comment: Hmm S3DEV , this is the final result so, I will not make next calculations, this is the reason why I need % symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.endswith` for `index` of the dataframe to check if a value ends with `_perc`, then assign the value converted to string plus percentage sign to such row values, otherwise just the default value. You can use `np.where` for this:

```py
for col in df:
    df[col] = np.where(df.index.str.endswith('_perc'), df[col].astype(str).add(' %'), df[col])

           col1     col2
IDX                     
X_sum     548.0   1200.0
X_perc   3.82 %  57.45 %
Y_sum     123.0    435.0
Y_perc  11.98 %  22.87 %
```

You can also use `.loc` accessor if you don't want to use np.where:

```py
for col in df:
    df.loc[df.index.str.endswith('_perc'), col] = df[col].astype(str).add(' %')

           col1     col2
IDX                     
X_sum     548.0   1200.0
X_perc   3.82 %  57.45 %
Y_sum     123.0    435.0
Y_perc  11.98 %  22.87 %
```

Comment: IDX is index do you remember about it ? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'IDX': {0: 'X_sum', 1: 'X_perc', 2: 'Y_sum', 3: 'Y_perc'},
 'col1': {0: 548.0, 1: 3.82, 2: 123.0, 3: 11.98},
 'col2': {0: 1200.0, 1: 57.45, 2: 435.0, 3: 22.87}})

(
    df.assign(col1=np.where(df.IDX.str.endswith('_perc'), df.col1.astype(str) + '%', df.col1))
    .assign(col2=np.where(df.IDX.str.endswith('_perc'), df.col2.astype(str) + '%', df.col2))
)

    IDX     col1    col2
0   X_sum   548.0   1200.0
1   X_perc  3.82%   57.45%
2   Y_sum   123.0   435.0
3   Y_perc  11.98%  22.87%
```

If `IDX` is index, use:

```
(
    df.assign(col1=np.where(df.index.str.endswith('_perc'), df.col1.astype(str) + '%', df.col1))
    .assign(col2=np.where(df.index.str.endswith('_perc'), df.col2.astype(str) + '%', df.col2))
)
```